# Can someone help me with htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I need someone to help me with a htaccess file to redirect my urls.

```
https://www.example.com/?a=support to https://www.example.com/support
https://www.example.com/?a=register to https://www.example.com/register
https://www.example.com/?a=login to https://www.example.com/login
https://www.example.com/?a=contact to https://www.example.com/contact
```

How to do this.

Comment: Proper questions start with showcasing your prior research or attempts, not "help me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named ".htaccess" in yours website root (https://www.example.com). In that file, put (or append) the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?a=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must capture the path and append it as a query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^a=
RewriteRule ^.*$ /?a=$0 [L]
```